Five types of Grain and Five Nations source
As we know from mishna Challah 1:1

Five species [of grains] are subject to [the law of] challah: wheat (חִטִּים), barley (שְּׂעוֹרִים), spelt (כֻּסְּמִין), oats (שִׁבֹּלֶת שׁוּעָל) and rye (שִׁיפוֹן).

(There is some controversy regarding designation of oats: it does not grow in Eretz Israel and is used in translation only due to second opinion in Sefer haArukh.) According to the Mishna Challah 4:1:

Two women who made [separate doughs] from two [separate] kavs, and these [doughs] touched one another, even if they are of the same species, they are exempt [from hallah]. When they belong to one woman: If one species [comes into contact] with the same species, they are subject [to separation of challah]. If different species, they are exempt.

The touching in the mishna is understood that the pieces of dough stick to each other. The explanation of what constitutes the same species is given in the next mishna 4:2:

What counts as same species? Wheat is not reckoned together with any [species] other than with spelt; Barley is reckoned together with all [species] except wheat. Rabbi Yohanan ben Nuri says: the rest of the species are reckoned together one with another.

We have 5 nations living in the vicinity of Eretz Israel: Israel, Edom, Moav, Ammon, and Ishmael. If Israel is wheat, Edom is barley, Ishmael is spelt, Moav is rhye and Ammon is oats, we find that the above laws of challah have parallels to laws of marriages between Jews and converts from these nations, as the Torah tells about restrictions on marriages with them Devarim 23:4, 8-9:

No Ammonite or Moabite shall be admitted into the congregation of Hashem; no descendants of such, even in the tenth generation, shall ever be admitted into the congregation of Hashem. ... You shall not abhor an Edomite, for such is your kin. You shall not abhor an Egyptian, for you were a stranger in that land. Children born to them may be admitted into the congregation of Hashem in the third generation. (meaning of residence in Israel’s territory).

In other words Jews, like wheat, do not stick well with Edom, Moav, and Ammon.
Is there any midrashic source to explore the parallel? Certainly it implies some importance to having the challah bread made out of wheat.
